# Formatting Date in Spreadsheet

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, logging

I have a column in spreadsheet that is 'date'.
When I retrieve the date with the following code,

```
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) {
  var row = data[i];
  var date= row[0];
  Logger.log(date);
```

I get

> Wed Nov 12 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT)

Is there a way to just show the output as

> Wed Oct 15 2014

I tried converting to JSON since it is an object, so that I can use substring

```
startDate = JSON.stringify(startDate); 
startDate = startDate.substring(0, 14);
```

But it doesn't output correctly.

> "2014-11-12T16:00:00.000Z"

Comment: Please read comment on answer below about GMT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using "formatDate" in Utilities class

- formatDate(date, timeZone, format)

try doing this:

```
var dateToFormat = row[0];
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateToFormat), "GMT", "EEE, MMM d, yyyy");
Logger.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: You should avoid using "GMT" for the timezone, all users living in a country that uses daylight savings will get in trouble... prefer using Session.getScripTimeZone() that will adapt automatically.

Comment: there's a typo in function name - 't' in Script is missing. it's Session.getScriptTimeZone(): https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getScriptTimeZone()

Answer (score 2):

Use formatDate() from the "Utilities" class:

```
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)

Comment: Same comment as above about time zone.